# Facebook Like Box not working

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to integrate a Like box in my website. It wasn't working, so I created a sample page (which also doesn't work).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>FB TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?profile_id=185550966885&amp;width=292&amp;connections=5&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm also using the sample iframe code (mine didn't work, so I tried this), taken from:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

The sample page is here:

http://www.plugb.com/fb-test.php

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the code they generate.  If you replace "profile_id" with "id" in the URL they generate it should work.